# Bootstrap text in vertical navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put together a sidebar in Bootstrap 3, but I want some items grouped under headings, like this

```
historical data
 temperature 
 humidity
current data
 temperature
 humidity
```

But "historical data" and "current data" are not links themselves -- they are just headers to group similar items together. This should be a simple modification of basic pattern, but it fails.

The code I tried is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-inverse">
  <li>
   <p class="sidebar-text> Historical data</p>
   <ul class="nav">
     <li> <a href="..."> Temperature </a> </li>
     <li> <a href="..."> Humidity </a> </li>
   </ul>
   <li>
  <li>
   <p class="sidebar-text> Live data</p>
   <ul class="nav">
     <li> <a href="..."> Temperature </a> </li>
     <li> <a href="..."> Humidity </a> </li>
   </ul>
   <li>
 </ul>
```

This is almost exactly the same as the pattern used on bootstrap documentation pages, except that bootstrap documentation uses links for main sections, and I replaced the link elements with `<p class="sidebar-text">`

However, the result looks wrong. The sublists are placed to the right of the textinstead of under it[image]

I made a bootply demo to see the results: http://www.bootply.com/XDM10D9I83

Is there a way to make this work without forcing section headers to be links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could look into [metisMenu](http://demo.onokumus.com/metisMenu/)? It's basically offering what you're trying to achieve :)

Or if you're already set on making the side nav on your own, here's what I think. If I understand your question correctly, you just want to make you're `<p>` element behave like an `<a>` element inside the `nav` right?

So why not target the css directly? Like for example here's the original CSS responsible for the output of the `<a>` tag

```
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

You could just replace the **a** to **p** to target the `<p>` elements:

```
    .nav>li>p:hover, .nav>li>p:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    .nav>li>p {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }
```

this would target those `<p>` elements inside the nav, and make it perform like an `<a>` element. Ofcourse, this is just an example :) you have to get the exact css fields that makes the `<a>` perform as it is.

Also, don't overwrite your original Bootstrap files. Make a separate CSS file and put your custom styles there :)

Comment: Yes, this works. To elaborate a bit more on what I didn't understand with the original code (after looking at this example and some more investigation): using `navbar-text` inside the `nav` is the wrong idea. It's intended for horizontal navbars and adds `float:left` to the style, which is the source of trouble. There is no class for styling text within `nav` elements in boostrap, so you have to write your own styling, as this answer suggests.

Comment: In my own implementation, I would not define the `p:hover` and `p:focus` attributes because I would not want the header element to be highlighted like a link (which is why I didn't want to use `a` in the first place). But the point remains - just styling the `li:p` elements is the right thing to do. And if using LESS, it is possible to use variables to copy over the styling, e.g., `padding: @nav-link-padding;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure

```
  <nav class="col-xs-3">
    <ul id="sidebar" class="fixed">
        <li>
           historical data
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#GroupASub1"> temperature </a></li>
                <li><a href="#GroupASub2"> humidity</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            current data
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#GroupBSub1"> temperature</a></li>
                <li><a href="#GroupBSub2"> humidity</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/0XwafzGNrr)!

Comment: I specifically asked about making "current data" and "historical data" text and not `<a>` elements like in your example because in my application they do not make sense as links. Because of various constraints, I cannot make these sections on the same page, but all subitems are links to different pages. "Current data" and "historical data" cannot take the user to a sensible page by themselves. That's why I would like them be text rather than `<a href>` elements.

Comment: @myrosia same thing - just remove the a tag from those items and it works!

Comment: This only works if you don't use `class="nav"` in your `ul`. But if you do that, you also lose the benefits of the `nav` class, like a color scheme for hover on links etc. With `class="nav"` your solution does not work. Dominic's answer above, to add your own style since `nav` does not provide a default for text, is the right one.

Comment: Why are the `p` tags a bad idea? Per html5 spec, any flow content is allowed within `li`, and this includes `p` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element). Is this something specific to bootstrap?

Comment: **Semantically** using a paragraph tag inside a list is wrong. However, **structure**-wise it still make sense. The CSS would still work :) @nolawipetros's answer is not wrong, but you do still need to make your own CSS for it to behave properly like what it's originally intended to.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in the same `<ul>` as the links, and then style them with a custom class:

**Example Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/GYJxbRpFS3**

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="sidebar-text">Current data</li>
  <li><a href="#"> Temperature</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Humidity</a></li>                        
</ul>
```

Custom class

```
.sidebar-text{
  font-size:18px;
  margin:10px;  
  color:white;
}
```